# Find the equation of a locus

Tags: geometry

$A$ and $B$ have coordinates $(1,1)$ and $(2,2)$ respectively. What is the equation of the locus of the point $P(x,y)$, if triangle $APB$ has an area of $10$ units?

Comment: Since the base of the triangle is fixed, if the area is constant, the height of the triangles must be the same. Thus $P$ lies on a line parallel to the base at a distance $20/AB$ from $AB$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint. If  $P=(x,y)$ belongs to the locus then
$$\frac{|AB|h}{2}=10$$
where $h$ is the height dropped from $P$ to $AB$. Then $|AB|=\sqrt{(2-1)^2+(2-1)^2}=\sqrt{2}$.

What is the formula for $h$? What is the equation of the locus?

Recall that the distance of a point $(x,y)$ from a line $aX+bY+c=0$ is given by
$$\frac{|ax+by+c|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}.$$
Moreover $AB$ is along the line $X-Y=0$.

Comment: Thanks Robert Z. I was trying to use an unnecessarily difficult method of trying to find an angle between two of the lines of the triangle and using (1/2)absinC to work out the area the triangle, equate that to ten, giving a locus for x and y.

Comment: @Amrit Cassim OK. Finally the locus is a couple of lines parallel to $AB$. BTW If you are new here take a few minutes for a tour https://math.stackexchange.com/tour

Answer (score 1):

If you can understand the formula for the [(oriented) triangle area as determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle#Using_coordinates), you just need to expand the determinant in $\begin{vmatrix}x&x_A&x_B\\y&y_A&y_B\\1&1&1\end{vmatrix}=\pm20$ using $(x_A,y_A)=(1,1)$ and $(x_B,y_B)=(2,2)$. This gives you the two equations (one for each of $\pm$) directly.